# SmartGWT ComboBox default checked items

Tags: combobox, smartgwt

I am using GWT combobox with Select item (dropdown checkbox)
I want to make some items defaultly checked, but i cant find any solutions..

```
@Override
            protected void success(List<warehouseDTO> t)
            {
                warehouse_list = t;
                for (int i = 0; i < warehouse_list.size(); i++)
                {
                    whl.put(warehouse_list.get(i).getId() + "", warehouse_list.get(i).getName());
                }
                selectItemMultiplePickList.setValueMap(whl);
                selectComboForm.setItems(selectItemMultiplePickList);
            }
```

On new "Article" (thing in warehouse) its good, but on edit i need to have checked by default.

Maybe its posible with setAttribute but cant find list of attributes.

Thanks

Comment: Which widget toolkit are you using? GXT? SmartGWT? Edit your question with the answer and don't forget to add a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the following:

```
setValues(values);
```

Here `values` accepts multiple String values.

Now as you're doing:

```
whl.put(warehouse_list.get(i).getId() + "", warehouse_list.get(i).getName());
```

your key for the combobox will be `warehouse_list.get(i).getId()` and value will be `warehouse_list.get(i).getName()`.

So to show multiple values as selected values, you need to pass multiple `warehouse_list.get(i).getId()` as `values`.

For example, if you want show first 3 values as selected, you can do the following:

```
selectItemMultiplePickList.setValues(
warehouse_list.get(0).getId(),
warehouse_list.get(1).getId(),
warehouse_list.get(2).getId());
```